# Call Azure ML Batch Job via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I have scheduled the Azure ML Batch Job via Azure Data Factory to run daily at 12:00 AM UTC.

Don't know what is the issue, but it is failing for every month's 3rd day, otherwise it runs perfectly.

Anybody facing same issue?

**For September**

[image: Error Log that display in Azure Data Factory for September]

**For October**

[image: Error Log that display in Azure Data Factory for October]

[image: Azure ML Batch Service Job Log]

Comment: Can you provide details of the error messages supplied?

Comment: @NickFry-CSL Hi, I have attached the error log screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ADF is successfully invoking ML and reporting back the "not converging" error. Could there be something specific in the input data that could cause this problem? Is there anything in the ML model that is handling dates as monthly that could be impacted by daily execution, around the start/end of the month (especially if there is any data offset or delay)?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely data related. The error is being returned from the batch execution system when the model is trying to score the data. I would look for duplicate Ids being inserted. Or any specific data that is being passed that could cause problems for this model. 
Having the job id and the Azure region this is running would help us look up the specific error.

Comment: region is West Europe

Comment: Can you also post the job id? There is no security risk in sharing that. It is internal to the system.